# getting rid of .html using Apache on EC2

Tags: html, amazon-ec2

Is there a simple way to remove the .html from a URL namespace? For example, if I have `www.mywebsite.com/special.html` how can I make this `www.mywebsite.com/special`

Again, I'm using Apache on an Amazon EC2 instance. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why don't you just use `mod_rewrite`? You can do nearly everything with it.

Comment: I am assuming that @Mobie is a beginner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.html$ /$1
```

Make sure that `mod_rewrite` is installed and `AllowOverride` includes `FileInfo`.

**Edit on how to get `mod_rewrite` working:**

Usually, `mod_rewrite` already comes with apache, but sometimes needs to be enabled by the command

```
a2enmod rewrite
```

The `AllowOverride` directive sets permissions for `.htaccess` files. For `mod_rewrite`, `FileInfo` is required. To set this, change in your apache config file (usually `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`) the line

```
AllowOverride None
```

to

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

or

```
AllowOverride All
```

Comment: Also a good answer. You may want to explain a little bit more about how to install `mod_rewrite` as well as how to make sure `AllowOverride` include `FileInfo`.

Comment: @edhedges Thank you, that's a good point. I've now made an edit to my answer, which explains how to get `mod_rewrite` working. But of course, more details about `mod_rewrite` could be found all over the internet, too.

Comment: @matthias.p I can't seem to edit the httpd.conf file properly using vi. It keeps saying that they is a swap file. Should I delete this file?

Comment: @Mobie Yes, you can delete this swap file. Its name should be `.httpd.conf.swp`. It seems that vim automatically creates such files sometimes. BTW: I've just looked at my apache config and on me in the `apache2.conf` **after** the `httpd.conf` is included there are included the `sites-available/` configurations which could overwrite the `AllowOverride`. I don't know if that's the case on your system too, but be aware that you might have to change your `/etc/httpd/sites-available/default` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Make a directory named `special` and put an `index.html` inside of it with the markup from `special.html`.